# pyqt4: QTableWidget cell coloring causes drag-and-drop

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I create a table and a button with:

```
self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
self.table.setObjectName('table')
self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
self.table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
self.table.setDragDropMode(False)
self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.table)

self.btn_del = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
self.btn_del.setObjectName('btn_del')
self.btn_del.setEnabled(False)

QtCore.QObject.connect(self.btn_del, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.del_feat)
```

When the user marks rows in the table and clicks the button, the selected rows should be colored. Therefor I use this:

```
def del_feat(self):

    del_list = []
    for i in self.table.selectionModel().selectedRows():
        del_list.append(i.row())


    col = len(self.columns) 


    brush_gray = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(232,232,232))
    brush_gray.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)

    for r in del_list[:]:
        for i in range(col):
            self.ui_c.table.item(r,i).setBackground(brush_gray)
```

The coloring is working but somehow, when I use this coloring method, the value of the cell which was clicked for selecting the rows is written into the last cell the mouse is over. When the cells doesn't get colored and only selected nothing happens. I've tried it with `setDragDropMode(False)` but it has no effect. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

TIA Martin

Answer (score 0):

Try to disconect cellChanged signal (if you're using it) and than connect it again, that worked for me... like this:

```
self.disconnect(self.table, QtCore.SIGNAL("cellChanged(int, int)"),self.someMethod)             
...... do setBeckground stuff...
self.connect(self.table, QtCore.SIGNAL("cellChanged(int, int)"),self.someMethod)
```

or disable / enable mainWindow in witch your table is...
I hope that helpes.